# How to setup Jenkins with ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, jenkins, asp.net-core, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a Pipeline on Jenkins, to automate my build, test and deploy process.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        myVersion = '0.9'
    }
    tools {
        msbuild '.NET Core 2.0.0'
    }
    stages {
        stage('checkout') {
          steps {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', ...])
          }
        }
        stage('restore') {
            steps {
                bat 'dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.Config'
            }
        }
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                bat 'dotnet build'
            }
        }
        stage('publish') {
            steps {
              ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to run the build, I get this error message from Jenkins:

**'dotnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

What do I have to change to make this environment work?

I added my .NET CORE path etc. to the Jenkins Settings for MSBuild.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
environment {
    myVersion = '0.9'
    dotnet = 'path\to\dotnet.exe'
}
```

and than replaced my command with the `%dotnet%` variable.